# Problemas para configurar el boton "eliminar" de la base datos de mi App

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, crud, nextjs, prisma

[image: frontend]estoy haciendo una app con Nextjs12 y prisma y lleva una base de datos mysql el problema es que al configurar el botón de "Eliminar" no logro que funcione y no doy con la solución.

lo estoy manejando en dos archivos el primero es el "context"(imagen frontend) de mi app y el otro es un archivo "api"(imagen backend).

me parece que el detalle pudiese estar en la forma que paso el "id" del elemento a eliminar.

[[image: backend][1]]

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema como texto, no como imagen.